# How to implement a custom dataset to pytorch project

Tags: python, dataset, pytorch

I’d like to train a NN with a given dataset (all including some kind of object, for example: a dog), after the training the NN should help me classifying my images (downloaded from instagram) as “image includes a dog (with probability:0.XX)” or “image doesn’t include a dog (with probability: 0.XX)”.

Obviously images from instagram-images do not always have the same size (but they all have the same format (.jpg) due to filtering), and the images from my dataset do not have the same size as well.

While testing, I'm getting this Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/nn.py", line 129, in <module>
    train(model=globalModel, hardware=hw, train_loader=loader, optimizer=optimizer, epoch=1)
  File "/venv/nn.py", line 74, in train
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 345, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 384, in _next_data
    index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 339, in _next_index
    return next(self._sampler_iter)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\sampler.py", line 200, in __iter__
    for idx in self.sampler:
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\sampler.py", line 62, in __iter__
    return iter(range(len(self.data_source)))
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

with this code: https://pastebin.com/DcvbeMcq

Does anyone know how to implement a custom dataset right?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that you're passing not the instance of `customDataset`, but the class type itself.
Try changing your loader creation code to

```
loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(customDataset(), batch_size=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed all previous bugs and errors. At the moment I'm trying to Label my Input data manually via PyTorch:

```
train_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=TRAIN_DATA_PATH, transform=TRANSFORM)
```

In the Folder TRAIN_DATA_PATH are many pictures of, for example, dogs. 
How can I manually label them all as "dogs" ?
I tried to implement the train data as traindataloader to label them, but it doesn't work until now.

```
train_data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)
```

Since I just want to get my evaluation data predicted as "dog (1)" or "not dog (0)", I have to label all of my dog images as "1" or "dog". 
But how can I do that?

Thanks to every reader!

Updated code (testing level): https://hastebin.com/axuvupihed.py